# having toubles importing bootstrap4-toggle to angular 8

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am new to Angular and I'm trying to import bootstrap4-toggle from this source:
https://gitbrent.github.io/bootstrap4-toggle/#api
to my project to add well a toggle checkbox :)
I run the npm install and I have the package in the project found in packjage.json, now I need to add it to "styles" but I don't know what to add, I've tried

```
 "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap4-toggle/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
```

but it didn't work...
I've used this tag in the navbar

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
```

and it supposed to look like a toggle button and instead it looks like a normal html check box.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? Do you get an error message? Please share as much details as you can.

Comment: Maybe you should just use the standard, pure-css ones, and avoid adding a dependency on jQuery to your application: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#switches

Comment: You need to import bootstrap4-toggle.min.js too, under scripts.

Comment: @JBNizet, hbamithkumara - both suggestion works, thank you!

Comment: @error86 - it appears that the answer has been posted by someone, and that you accepted it as such. Please do not edit your question to say "solved" or put the solution in the question - that's not where it goes, and those are invalid edits to a question. If you want to post an additional answer, with specifics in addition to the answer posted, that would be great. As such... I rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add imports at scripts and styles in angular.json

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap4-toggle/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap4-toggle/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"
]
```